# Angular 8; How to show image by url in ngx-input-file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm using ngx-input-file component in my Angular 8 project. It is really straight forward to upload files including images by it. However I need to display images that are already uploaded and user needs to change them.

```
<input-file placeholder="ImageList" formControlName="projectMainPicture" fileLimit="5" fileAccept="image/*" ></input-file>
```

Moreover, I'm using reactive approach:

```
this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        projectMainPicture: ['', [FileValidatorDirective.validate]]
      });
this.editForm.get('projectMainPicture').setValue(project.projectImageList.map(x => x.thumbnail));
```

the thumbnail field contains url of the uploaded image on the server.
but the result is as below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:

```
          currentImages = new Array<InputFile>();
          project.projectImageList.map( (x, i) => {
            this.toDataURL(`../../assets/projects/small/${x.projectId}_${i + 1}.jpg`, (dataUrl) => {
              const inputFile: InputFile = { id: i + 1, preview: dataUrl, file: dataUrl };
              this.currentImages.push(inputFile);
              return this.currentImages;
                    });
          });
          this.editForm.get('projectMainPicture')
          .setValue(this.currentImages);

toDataURL(url, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = () => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            callback(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}
```

First I create an array of InputFile which is an interface in the InputFileComponent and then get the image using XMLHTTPRequest and put the base64 format of the picture in the fields of InputFile